# C# programming to get name node from XML

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

How to get value of node "name" from below XML.

```
`XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\New folder\Sample_Rajnish_1.xml");
MessageBox.Show(doc.SelectSingleNode("ConfData/CfgAgentGroup/CfgGroup/name").InnerText);`
```

Below is the sample XML file`    SATRCFG_OBJECT [xml] =

```
<ConfData>
  <CfgAgentGroup>
    <CfgGroup>
      <DBID value="225"/>
      <tenantDBID value="101"/>
      <name value="CBD"/>
      <routeDNDBIDs>
        <DBID value="825"/>
      </routeDNDBIDs>
      <capacityTableDBID value="0"/>
      <quotaTableDBID value="0"/>
      <state value="1"/>
      <capacityRuleDBID value="0"/>
      <siteDBID value="0"/>
      <contractDBID value="0"/>
    </CfgGroup>
    <agentDBIDs>
      <DBID value="128"/>
      <DBID value="133"/>
      <DBID value="135"/>
      <DBID value="385"/>
      <DBID value="433"/>
    </agentDBIDs>
  </CfgAgentGroup>
</ConfData>
```

Request your suggestion.

Thanks in advance!!
Rajnish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

```cs
XElement data = XElement.Load(@"C:\New folder\Sample_Rajnish_1.xml");

String value = data.Element("CfgAgentGroup").Element("CfgGroup")
                                            .Element("name")
                                            .Attribute("value")
                                            .Value;
```